# Genearalisation of previous MSE question regarding password combinatorics in $n$ dimensions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507466/how-many-passwords-can-be-formed) caught my atention recently. Most (if not all) of the answers aproached the problem via a brute force attack. Surely there is a more elegant way to deal with this, given the inherent symmetry.

My question is can this be generalised to an $n$ dimensional lattice? Clearly the placement of the nearest neighbour is critical in this problem *(ie, it is unclear where $n=5$ in $2$ dimensions would be places in terms of the classical Descatrian coordinate system)*, but it could also be generalised to $n$ in any dimension. Is this a Hamiltonian path *(ie NP hard problem)*, or can the symmetry be utilised to present a more analytic solution?

**Note**

If standard MSE policy of questions being self-contained is desired, please note, and I will alter.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by symmetry?

Comment: @MattSamuel Clearly one vertec needs to be consisered  and mutliplied by 4. The same goes of the mid- sides, and the centre is the exception. The problem lies of course in the topological issue of not retracing your steps.

Comment: *Surely there is a more elegant way to deal with this, given the inherent symmetry.* - Surely there is a God, given the inherent order present in the Universe.

Comment: @Lucien oh, the irony ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your "dots" form the vertices of a graph, and I think you're asking for the number of self-avoiding walks of a given length on this graph.   There is a huge literature on self-avoiding walks.
In general, counting self-avoiding walks is #P-complete, and thus very difficult: see e.g.
[this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030439750300080X).

Comment: this is an interesting comment. I suppose the question of how to apply it will rely on my own research - made easier by the link you provided - many thanks :)